# swf doesn't respond when relocating it

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, flash, deployment

i have in my program few swf files and using mxmlc i compile the application into one swf file.
when i open the swf from the output directory(just dbl click) everything works fine.
But, when i copy the directory to another location in the hardisk the application stops responding
(i can see my swf main picture and its buttons in it.
But, when i click a button which just popup a message, it doesn't work!)
Note: any location in my workspace, the swf still works fine. But when moving out the workspace it fails
any help?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Are you using a web server & HTTP or are you using the 'file' syntax to test your swf?  Can you share code and/or screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, 
copying the build swf to another directory changes the trusted mechanism of flash .
I published more    exact question